How can I ensure that the container is at least as wide as the longest text and that the entire text is visible?
I have a navigation dropdown menu within a container. The HTML and CSS code provided is meant to display a language dropdown menu. However, I'm experiencing issues where the container's width doesn't adjust according to the length of the longest text inside it. I want to ensure that the container is always at least as wide as the longest text and that the entire text is visible. How can I achieve this with the given code?


* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.language {
  list-style: none;
  background: #22438C;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul.dropdown li {
  display: block;
}

ul.dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  background: #22438C;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background: #112C66;
}

.container:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
}
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="language" href="#">EN ▾</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>




Remove position: absolute; in ul.dropdown.

As long as the children of the container's dropdown are hidden they do not contribute to the container's width. It's not clear why the container's width is an issue, just removing the width:100% from your .dropdown class improves the look of the dropdown links.

I think if you want it to look appropriate
just add width that is larger from 100%
and also add to the body a max-width.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can add width: fit-content; to ul. dropdown div, but doing so will only extend the length of the links, not the dropdown title. If this matters, I'd say adding a width that's equal to however long your longest link will be to the main dropdown. For example, if your largest link would be 150px long, adding that width to your language class would ensure everything is the same length!
